# Using sed to extract the middle of a line/filename

Tags: bash, sed

I have multiple files named:

`Genus_species_strain.fasta`

I want to use sed to print out:

`Genus`

`species`

`strain`

I want to use the "printed" words in a command like this (prokka is a tool for genome annotation):

```
prokka $file --outdir `echo $file | sed s/\.fasta//` --genus `echo $file | sed s/_.*\.fasta//` --species `echo $file | sed <something here>` --strain `echo $file | sed <something here>`
```

I would appreciate the help. I am very new to all of this, and as you see above, I only know how to print out `Genus`.

Below I have some additional questions (no need to answer these if it only complicates things further). This is one of my attempts to print `species`, and the questions are the following:

```
sed s/.*_//1 | sed s/_.*\.fasta//
```

1. I know the second command isn't correct. I assume it needs to start from the second `_`, but I don't know how to do that, since the continuation (that is `.fasta`) is unique.
2. When used alone, `sed s/.*_//1` returns `strain.fasta`. How to make it not skip the first `_`?
3. Combining commands (either as you see above, or with `;`) doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is, I want to use the "printed" words in a command like this: prokka $file --outdir `echo $file | sed s/\.fasta//` --genus `echo $file | sed s/_.*\.fasta//` --species <> --strain <>. (Sorry I'm not good at formatting this) I will edit my post to show this, too

Comment: You can still use `IFS='[_.]' read -r a b c _ <<< "$s"` and then `prokka $file --outdir "$a" --genus "$b"...`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/1NAddd). Or, `IFS='[_.]' read -r genus species strain _ <<< "$file"` with more verbose names. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/8WIbsE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string splitting with string manipulation:

```sh
file='Genus_species_strain.fasta'
IFS='[_.]' read -r genus species strain _ <<< "$file"
outdir="${file%.*}"
```

Then you can use the variables in the command:

```sh
prokka "$file" --outdir "$outdir" --genus "$genus" --species "$species" --strain "$strain"
```

See this online demo:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
file='Genus_species_strain.fasta'
IFS='[_.]' read -r genus species strain _ <<< "$file"
echo "${file%.*}" # outdir
echo "$genus"
echo "$species"
echo "$strain"
```

Output:

```
Genus_species_strain
Genus
species
strain
```

Answer (score 1):

One liners without setting multiple varibles
**Using sed capture groups:
One liner**

```
file='Genus_species_strain.fasta'
$(echo "$file" | sed "s/\(^[^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)\.\(.*\)/prokka "$(echo "$file")" --outdir \4 --genus \1 --species \2 --strain \3/")
```

**Using Bash string manipulation:
One liner**

```
file='Genus_species_strain.fasta'
$(echo prokka "$file" --outdir `echo "${file#*.}"` --genus `echo "${file%%_*}"` --species "$(echo `file=${file#*_} && echo "${file%%_*}"`)" --strain "$(echo `file=${file#*_} && file=${file#*_} && echo "${file%%.*}"`)")
```

**Awk one liner**

```
file='Genus_species_strain.fasta'
$(echo "$file" | awk -F [_\.] -v var="$file" '{print "prokka " $var " --outdir " $4 " --genus " $1 " --species " $2 " --strain " $4}')
```

Now you can use above commands within loop or with xargs with file variable pointing to filenames.
It will create a prokka command and directly evaluates/executes it.

Hoping it works for you. Accept answer if it is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ file=path_to_file
$ sed "s/\(\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\([^.]*\)\).*/prokka $file --outdir \1 --genus \2 --species \3 --strain \4/e" <(echo *.fasta)
```

Output of command executed

```
prokka path_to_file --outdir Genus_species_strain --genus Genus --species species --strain strain
```